# Facebook server time in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, clock

Im trying to show on my site changeable clock synchronized with facebook server.
The fb server time is available at:
    https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+now%28%29+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+%3D+%271.2%27&format=json

How to make it changeable every second without refreshing the page?

Comment: The server time is `[{"anon":1354654854}]`???

Comment: yes but it is in unix timestamp format ;)

Comment: Oh, it really is seconds since epoch. Would've expected a more descriptive format; hope this format does not change for non-anon users.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming some non-written functions, it should look like that:

```
var requestBegin = Date.now();
getServertimeFromFacebook(function callback(fbTime) {
    var requestEnd = Date.now();
    var latency = (requestEnd - requestBegin) / 2;
    var curDevicetime = Date.now(); // = requestEnd, of course
    var difference = fbTime - latency - curDeviceTime;

    function clock() {
        var cur = Date.now();
        var curFbTime = cur + difference;
        show(curFbTime); // print, log, whatever
    };
    setInterval(clock, …); // you could use a self-adjusting clock
                           // by using a setTimeout for each tick
});
```

You could do

```
show = function(t) { console.log(new Date(t).toString()); };
getServertimeFromFacebook = function(cb) {
    ajax("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+now%28%29+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+%3D+%271.2%27&format=json", function(responsetext) {
         var obj = JSON.parse(responsetext);
         var ts = obj[0].anon,
             tms = ts * 1000;
         cb(tms);
    });
};
```

Comment: how i can print clock from second script on the page?

Comment: What do you mean by "on the page"? Just use a `show` function that displays it via DOM manipulation.

Comment: You can't `document.write` to already loaded documents, you will need to use DOM manipulation. `show` is not a pre-defined function, you will need to define it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call the API every second.

Instead, I would get the Facebook server time only one time at the beginning. And then, I would increment my **time** value every second by looping using javascript :

`setTimeout(function() { /* increment time */ }, 1000);`

Bergi: `[{"anon":1354654854}]` is a [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Indeed, Facebook often (always?) deals with time using this representation.

Comment: Im trying to get the time like this to put it in yours script ` $sql = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT now()");` but it doesnt work for me.